# Ubuntu 12.04/12.10 Keeps on Freezing

Tags: 12.04, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Since I installed Ubuntu 12.04 it keeps on freezing. It happens on different PCs and I don't think it's a memory problem. For example, I recently got a laptoptop with 8Gb of RAM and I got the problem there as well. The only solution is unplugging the machine or pressing +REISUB (I found this magic spell in a related thread).

The problem seems to be triggered by a task switch, e.g. when I press <kbd>F12</kbd>, which moves guake to the background or into the foreground or when I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, which switches the current gui task.

I am suspecting guake, Chrome, or Evince are possible causes of the problem. However, I disabled guake on the laptop and I've seen the problem once since then.

I just reinstalled 12.10 and I had 3 freezes in 10 minutes. I wasn't doing anything special. The only thing I was doing was running Chrome and gimp.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem sometimes. There are 20 PC with Ubuntu OS in my office and just 1 of them had this problem randomly. I solved it by changing 32 bit to 64 bit. I think it is better to use the 64-bit version of Ubuntu with 8GB RAM (on your laptop). I do this and it helps most of the time.

Another possibility is a graphics card problem. I had a PC with Intel on-board graphics card and it was OK, but when I added an ATI graphic card to it, I had this problem again. This can be fixed by using the correct driver.

I've also solve this problem in the past by upgrading the kernel to the latest stable one, from [the mainline PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)

[Here's some instructions on upgrading the kernel](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/07/how-to-install-linux-kernel-3-5-quantal-in-ubuntu-12-04-11-10-11-04-10-10-and-10-04/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I may try this tomorrow:(. Your suggestion makes sent because I _definitely_ get many more freezes on my machine at hoe, which is configured as 32 bit. However, I also got the problem on my desktop at work, which is configured as 64 bit. (Same for laptop.)